# Why can't tuples in Scala be traversed?

Tags: scala, tuples, traversal

Suppose I create a `Tuple6`:

```
val tup = (true, 1 , "Hello" , 0.4 , "World" , 0 )
tup: (Boolean, Int, String, Float, String, Int)
```

And I can access the elements of the tuple using `._<position>` like
`tup._1` and `tup._2` and so on. But why does

```
for (i <- 1 to 6)
     println(tup._i)
```

give me an error saying that

```
value _i is not a member of (String, Int, Boolean, String, Double, Int)
```

I understand that it is clearly stated that **Tuples are not iterable**, but if `._1` works , shouldn't `._i` work the same way ?

Comment: The `1` in `_1` is not a literal integer, it's an arbitrary identifier. It could have been called `_xyz` and done the same thing, but that would have been confusing.

Comment: @m-z I'm sorry but I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion.

Comment: @m-z Oh, now I get it. Thanks

Comment: Tuples should not be thought of as collections, but as a kind of unnamed classes with a number of members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all boils down to **type**.

What type would you like a dynamic accessor such as `_<position>` to have? In the general case, the only valid one would be `Any`. In a strongly-typed language such as Scala this is useless for most purposes.

The good news is that the problem *can* be handled in a type-safe manner - see e.g. **the [`HList`-style tuple handling](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples)** in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

However, there is no such mechanism available in the standard Scala library (barring heavy metaprogramming such as macros).

Comment: Ok. But for instance, I create a tuple with all the elements being of the same type, say, strings, why doesn't it work ? Is it because the Tuple is designed to work only with **Any** type ?

Comment: Yankee: can you think of a lot of situations where such a tuple would be preferable as opposed to a `List`? And do you think those situations would justify the additional implementation type and API confusion (since it would be a fairly obscure exception)? Don't get me wrong, by the way - I use shapeless in a fair portion of my projects for exactly this purpose, so the need is certainly there. But it can't be handled by a dynamic accessor in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: There _is_ a way in standard scala: `tuple.productIterator.foreach(println)`

Comment: @Dima : I had a hunch that the question ultimately contains an implicit assumption of functional equivalence, so the answer was created in that context, to guide the OP towards the actual problem (and apparently that hunch has been vindicated). Incidentally, notice how all examples of `productIterator` here are paired with `println`?

Comment: @mikolak they are paired with `println` for lack of imagination, not for any specific technical reason. Consider `tuple.productIterator.map { case x: Int => x+1; case _ => 0 }`  Better? :)

Answer (score 6):

For tuples there is an `productIterator` method that gives you an opportunity to iterate over elements of tuple. But obviously each element of such iteration will be of type `Any`

Comment: Another way to do it using a similar method is : 

`for (i <- 0 to 6)  
    println(tup.productElement(i))`

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that it is clearly stated that **Tuples are not iterable**, but if `._1` works , shouldn't `._i` work the same way ?

Why should it? In one case you are calling the method `_1` (which does exist), in the other case you are calling the method `_i` (which doesn't exist). Calling two different methods usually does *not* "work the same way", especially if one of them doesn't even exist.

Comment: Yea, my bad. I didn't know it was a method call and a comment by @m-z cleared it out. Thanks for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an `Iterator[U]` where `U` is the least upper bound of the types `T1` to `Tn` of the tuple.

```
implicit class FancyTuple2[T1,T2,U](private val tuple: (T1 with U,T2 with U)) extends AnyVal { 
  def iterator: Iterator[U] = Iterator(tuple._1, tuple._2)
}
```

You'd have to write (or generate) this for every arity that you need a tuple of.